# Вернуть промис или как получить PromiseValue

Tags: javascript

Полога, что создаю дубль, но вдруг что-то изменилось) и есть решение вернуть значение примаса PromiseValue?

```js
async function praiceZeb() {

  let client = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    csvarray = [];
  client.open('GET', 'xls-test.csv');

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    client.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) {
        let rows = client.responseText.split('\n');
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          csvarray.push(rows[i].split(';'));
        }

        resolve(csvarray[5][1]);
      }
    };
    client.send();
  });
  return csvarray[5][1];
};

console.log(praiceZeb());
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо получить значение из `Promise`? Чтобы это сделать, тебе необходимо вызвать свою синхронной функцию `praiceZeb` из другой синхронной функции.

```js
async function praiceZeb() {
  const promiseValue = new Promise(resolve => {
    const arryaValue = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      arryaValue.push(i);
    };
    resolve(arryaValue);
  });
  return promiseValue;
};

(async() => {
  const result = await praiceZeb();
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Так как твой `console.log` выполняется асинхронно.

Comment: Не слишком ли много `async`?

Comment: @Рустам-Гимранов Я не знаю чего автор будет делать в промисе, может там тоже необходимо синхронно выполнять действия. Я только показал как можно сделать в.

Comment: @Рустам-Гимранов Я полагаю если у автора возникли проблемы пониманием `async/await`, то вероятно для общего развития можно было показать что промис тоже может быть синхронным. Так что я считаю не лишнее это было.

Comment: @Рустам-Гимранов Я ответил на вопрос автора, не более. Для чего с синхронному коду что-то обещать? Например, для работы с асинхронными библиотеками. Дальнейшее осуждение выходит за рамки вопроса. Если что то не понятно, читайте первое предложение в этом ответе.

Comment: если внутри `async` не используется `await` то и `async` не нужен. Сам промис не обязывает писать `async`

Comment: Так и не понял, можно передать или нет))?